# iOS Certificate Generation Error: Disc Quota Exceeded. Is this an Apple bug?

Tags: ios, certificate

I am having the same error that user2320456 was having two days back. They did manage to solve their problem and the issue was closed because the problem was too localized. But I do want to know (a) how they solved it or (b) if it was an Apple bug. The description of the problem follows below:

**I am trying to generate an iOS Development Certificate. After I select the .certSigningRequest file from my desktop and click on Generate, I get the following error:**

**Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Disc quota exceeded**

Why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like it is an Apple bug. Fixed itself.

Admins, when you close this question / thread, please retain the fact that it was an Apple issue.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now!

Comment: I got this error today

Answer (score 3):

Reason may be with these `three` lines.

```
Also make sure you use Safari for uploading.
```

But i fixed it by downloading the `WWDR Intermediate Certificate` before generating the `CSR`.

Go to '`Keychain First Aid`' in Keychain Access and you can `verify/repair` your config.

`UPDATE ONE`

as guys first case worked for me and this answer i did some Google and found some interseting facts like for some `iOS Developers` these things worked fine.

- I fix it. I restart my mac and upload the file again and then it works.
- I tried Chrome and it worked. I probably just needed to restart Safari.
- I had a similar problem. When creating a CSR for enabling push notifications, I first had to deselect the current selected key in Keychain Access before selecting Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority. That solved my problem

Comment: In my case these step don't work — I assume the issue is more server-side related. We surely have to wait for Apple!

Comment: yup, same for me, it's not generating the certificate. I do believe you are right about safari though, I think I remember it from the last time

Comment: I did it via Safari and also re-installed the WWDR and now it works ... yay apple ... sigh.

Comment: Guys i wasted 3 hours no result then change the browser and got the result. Really it is not fair :) and little funny too...